# gstreamer pipeline shows green image when used in c++ with cv::Mat

Tags: c++, image, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have a Gstreamer sender that pushes images to the udpsink and a receiver that shows the image on the other device.

Sender:
`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=195.0.0.50 port=9003`

Receiver:
`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9003 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

If I just use the pipelines with gst-launch-1.0 it works, but when i use the sender pipeline in C++  and try to write cv::Mats with cv::VideoWriter to the pipeline the image on the other device just gets green.

This is the Code

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>




int main(int arg, char *argv[]) {
    gst_init(&arg, &argv);

    cv::VideoWriter writer("appsrc  ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=195.0.0.50 port=9003 ", 0, (double)30, cv::Size(1920,1080), true);


    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    cap = cv::VideoCapture(0, cv::CAP_V4L2);
    while (1){
        auto start_preprocess= std::chrono::system_clock::now();
 
    
    cv::Mat img;
    cap >> img;
    writer << img;

    cv::imshow("w",img);
    cv::waitKey(1);


        std::cout << "--- time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start_preprocess).count() << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}
```